# Php mongodb not able to connect using username and password

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication

I am able to login to mongo using the following command:

```
mongo host_name:port/admin -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD'
```

For PHP I tried below code to connect to mongo:

```
try{
   $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@host_name:27017");

   echo "Connection to database successfully";

}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

But it is not connecting. Gives following error:

```
Failed to connect to: 10.7.0.225:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'USERNAME': auth failed
```

I have already created user `root` with role as `root`.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried the alternative method?
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));

Comment: Yes Paras I did. Actually the problem was with PHP-Mongo driver version. Version 1.4 had a bug. After upgrading to latest version, it worked!